# cannot import store from redux library in react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, redux

Im trying out the redux example on the official react-redux website [HERE](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial#providing-the-store) with the following javascript :

```js
// index.js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import TodoApp from './TodoApp'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from './redux/store'

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <TodoApp />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
)
```

But I get the following error :

```sh
Module not found: Can't resolve './redux/store' in '/mnt/d/Projects/engage-calculator/src'
```

my package.json is

```
{
  "name": "engage-calculator",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

What is wrong?? The codesandbox page has the same dirextory structure as mine i also tried named imports by using {} but nothing changed. I can assure you that redux is installed i did npm install many times

directory structure :

```sh
.
├── README.md
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── logo192.png
│   ├── logo512.png
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── robots.txt
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── components
    │   └── calculator.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    └── serviceWorker.js
```

Comment: can you list your files list?

Comment: @Mohammednaji wait a sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is that you should create your store, they used a custom path, so they created a folder called redux and a file called store file

```
- application
   - redux
     - store.js
```

so your path will be `./redux/store`

Comment: do we always have to create a store by ourselves. and if yes then where can I learn -from basics - how to make a store

Comment: you need to check redux documentation 
https://redux.js.org/basics/store
so you can learn how to create store